# object is not iterable JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an array of objects. But sometimes this is just a pure object and in such cases my loop fails. How do I prevent this.

```
   for(let singleItem of myObj){     // this works fine when I get an array of objects
            myArray.push({
                'Item 1': singleItem .Prop1.text,
                'Item 2': singleItem .Prop2.text
            })
        }
```

I get an error on `for.....of` when I have no array but just an Object with key values.

```
When I get the error, my object `myObj` will be like this.
{
   Prop1: { text: 'testvalue' },
   Prop2: { text: 'testvalue1' }
}
```

How do I ensure that I can fill my array `myArray` without any error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if `myArray` is object and then convert it to an array of one object.

```js
for(let singleItem of Array.isArray(myObj) ? myObj : [myObj]){
```

Comment: this should be answer to so many irrelevant answers here. perfect.